# How to align source note to the table in a gt table?

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

I am using R markdown into a pdf document, using gt() to make a table with a source note at the bottom. For some reason, the source note isn't center aligned to the table. How do I make it aligned to the table?

This is what comes out when I knit the PDF document, the source note is to the left and not centered with the table.
[image]

This is my data frame:

```
test_df<-
    structure(list(Year = c("2010", "2015", "2020"), Lehigh_County = c(350008, 
359689, 374557), Northampton_County = c(297941, 300264, 312951
), Lehigh_Valley = c(647949, 659953, 687508)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is the code to make it into a gt table:

```
    test_df %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_header(
    title = "Lehigh Valley Population Forecast",
    subtitle = "2020 - 2050"
  ) %>% 
  cols_label(
    Lehigh_County = "Lehigh County",
    Northampton_County = "Northamp. County",
    Lehigh_Valley = "Lehigh Valley"
  ) %>% 
  tab_source_note(source_note = "U.S. Census / REMI Forecasts") %>% 
  fmt_number(columns = c(Lehigh_County, Northampton_County, Lehigh_Valley), sep_mark = ",", decimals = 0)
```

It looks right when I generate the table, but when I knit, the source note shifts to the left. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick hack to allow you to keep working without having to worry about formatting, but if you render to `html_document` you are able to "print to pdf", which works in a pinch allowing for some HTML styling. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have such problem but you can try to explicitly set a style of the source_note using "tab_style" with "location" pointing to source notes.

```
tab_style(style = cell_text(align = "left"),locations = cells_source_notes())
```

It should force GT to rewrite source note field.
Hope that it helps.